# Issue with SELECTing a value from one coloumn that is dependant on another SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

A hard one to explain, The code below is what I am using to select values from a coloumn that are distinct and then counting the amount of times they occour

e.g.

```
product 1 = 100
product 2 = 52
```

however I need this to only use rows where a differnt coloumn called status = booking, I know that this can be done using WHERE status = `booking` somewhere in the code but I can't get the positioning right, any help?

```
select distinct product, count(product) as CountOf 
from sw_orders
group by product
```

Sample dataset

```
id | product | status
-----------------------
1  | pd1     | non
2  | pd2     |booking
3  | pd4     |booking
4  | pd2     |cancelled
5  | pd1     |booking
6  | pd1     |booking
7  | pd1     |booking
```

expected result

```
product| count
-----------------------
pd1  | 3
pd4  | 1
pd2  | 1
```

Comment: Sample data and desired resultset will be helpful. Probably it is simple condtional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use simple conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT product, SUM(status = 'booking') as CountOf 
FROM sw_orders 
GROUP BY product;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT product, SUM(status) As StatusCount 
FROM sw_orders 
WHERE status = 'booking'
GROUP BY product;
```